# I'm looking for a service that sends out OTP sms to validate phone numbers

Tags: authentication, sms

I'm looking for a service that provides an API interface to help validate phone numbers by sending out OTP. If you know any service that does the job, please advice!!

Comment: Please rewrite your question to focus on what you need exactly. Especially the title, it must be understandable by people who don't know about Facebook.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software

Comment: Please follow the advice at https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2833/140

Comment: In particular, remove the word "Facebook" from your question.

Comment: clean & clear :)